# Should I accept an edit on a closed question if it won't help it to be reopened?

Tags: discussion

Say that you got a nice edit in the edit review queue, however the question is closed and won't be opened over that edit.

If I accept it, the question will go to reopen queue for no reason at all- it won't be reopened over that edit.

If I reject it, the user that spent time editing will lose their effort.

I'll use [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/179847) as a context even though it conflicts with author intent. Think of it as an edit that would be nice on a non-closed question.

Should I post a [feature-request](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for <kbd>Accept but don't send to reopen queue</kbd> button (maybe a popup asking if you want it to be sent to reopen queue if you accept the edit on closed questions)?

Comment: On top of Wipqozn's answer, it's worth noting that your feature request (if implemented), could be open to abuse as there are definitely controversial on/off topics here: Not kicking it to the reopen review would mean you're deliberately making sure less eyeballs see the closed question post-edit: while you may do this to save people the time reviewing a crap question, others may use it to keep a question closed that *they* think is off topic, but 5 other people might think otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I accept an edit on a closed question if it won't help it to be reopened?

If it's a good edit, sure, go ahead. We keep duplicates around in order to make it easier for users to track down questions, so making the duplicate bodies better may assist in that.Sure, it'll get tossed into the reopen queue, but it really isn't a big deal to be honest.

> I'll use this as a context even though it conflicts with author intent. Think of it as an edit that would be nice on a non-closed question.

I wouldn't approve that edit, since it doesn't add anything to the question. aka reject as too minor.

> Should I post a feature-request for Accept but don't send to reopen queue button (maybe a popup asking if you want it to be sent to reopen queue if you accept the edit on closed questions)?

No. The use case for when this is useful is way too small to be worth the SE team spending any time on.